# How do I add up the value of column B if column A meets a certain condition for each value in column A with one formula?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Below is an example of the values I'm trying to add. My goal is not to use the filter formula for every line again. This is because it takes a lot of resources from the processing power that google sheets uses.

The words in the left list below occur several times in combination with a certain number. I want to have a unique list as shown on the right where the values from the left row add up when the words are equal (without using a filter formula for each line).

[image]

This formula

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(A:A, A:B, 2, FALSE)))
```

comes very close, but returns only one value even though there are multiple matches. I want all values that matches returned.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select A,sum(B) where A is not null group by A label sum(B)'summed'", 1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this. I'll think about the query formula more often when I try to solve a problem in google sheets. :-)